# Tornado server angular route

Tags: python, angularjs, tornado

When i land on / the angular app loads. When i query /something it fails. How should the tornado router be configured to route to the correct angular page?

Tornado:

```
app = web.Application([
    (r'/api/recFields', RecFieldHandler),
    (r'/api/recs', ApiHandler),
    (r'/api/ner', NerHandler),
    (r'/tagger', web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": SITE_PATH + '/views/tagger', "default_filename": "tagger.html"}),
    (r'/(.*)', web.StaticFileHandler, {"path": SITE_PATH, "default_filename": "index.html"})
    ])
```

Angular:

```
angular.module('html5app', [
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize'
    ])
    .config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function config ($locationProvider, $routeProvider){
        //enabling HTML5 mode
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false}).hashPrefix('!');

        //setting up routes
        $routeProvider.when('/',{ templateUrl: '/views/recs/recs.html', controller: 'RecCtrl as home'});
        $routeProvider.when('/tagger',{ templateUrl: '/views/tagger/tagger.html', controller: 'TaggerCtrl as home'});
    }])
```